# Create 2 different click once publish from the same project

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce, publish

I have an application which is running on machine with production database,I need to do a quick test against test database, for this I need to create the second publish which will start the new installation instead of updating the production application.[image]

I tried changing product name, but it just update the product name. Is there any setting available in publish, which forces the second publish to start a new installation instead of updating the old first one? 
Creating copy of the project will solve the problem, but it would be nice to create the 2 different publish from the same project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now changing assembly name and product name does the trick. But I wonder if its possible to publish both production and test simultaneously with different app and publish settings!!

Comment: thanks a deal! saved me a bit of frustration - changing assembly name worked. i am sure the same pattern (that worked without changing anything) used to work in VS2005 & VS2010, because i was doing it constantly, deploying to the intranet the same app, with different settings in app.config - in vs2015 this seems to have changed